# Concurrent Modification when using connection pool

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, proxool

I am trying to get the jdbc connection using proxool connection pool in a Web application. Below code describes the same :

```
public static Connection getConnection(String key, boolean useConnectionPool, String poolName) {
    Connection connection = null;
    String alias = "DBCP" + poolName + "_" + key;
    String driverClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    checkAndLoadProps();
    String driverUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + props.getProperty(key + "_DBMS_URL") + "/" + props.getProperty(key + "_DEF_SCHEMA") + "?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&rewriteBatchedStatement=true";
    String connectionPoolUrl = "proxool." + alias + ":" + driverClass + ":" + driverUrl;
    try {
        if (useConnectionPool) {
            info.remove("user");
            String user = props.getProperty(key + "_CLIENT");
            info.setProperty("user", user);
            info.remove("password");
            String password = props.getProperty(key + "_CLIENT_PASS");
            info.setProperty("password", password);
            String host = props.getProperty(key + "_DBMS_URL");

            synchronized (poolName) {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionPoolUrl, info);
            }

        } 
        if (connection != null) {
            return connection;
        } else {
            System.out.println("DB Connection Not Established");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("DB Connection Not Established::" + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What happens is as soon as I start my server, more than 1 threads try to access this code parallely and it throws concurrent modification exception.

I understand it can be fixed by providing class level lock to the synchronized block. But it will severely affect the performance.

Any better solution to this?

Comment: could you please add the stack trace?

Comment: Show also how you defined `info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your problem is more related to `info` which is obviously an instance of `Properties` that is shared. Knowing that `Properties` extends [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) and an  `Hashtable` will throw a  `ConcurrentModificationException` if you change its structure while iterating over it as stated into the javadoc:

> if the `Hashtable` is structurally modified at any time after the
>   iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own
>   remove method, the iterator will throw a
>   `ConcurrentModificationException`.

And here if you have several threads calling this method in parallel they could concurrently remove properties which modifies the structure of your `Hashtable` and iterate over it within `DriverManager.getConnection(connectionPoolUrl, info)` which would end up with a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

What you should do is convert `info` into a [`ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which is thread-safe and allows to be concurrently modified and iterated. Then you would provide as parameter to `DriverManager.getConnection`, a `Properties` instance created from `info` as next:

```
private static Map<Object, Object> info = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static Connection getConnection(String key, boolean useConnectionPool, 
    String poolName) {

    ...
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.putAll(info);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionPoolUrl, properties);
```

Comment: This was indeed the issue. I tried the fix you suggested and it worked !. Many Thanks !